# How does Javascript know when to execute a function passed by reference implicitly? React example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, pass-by-reference

In my React example app, I am passing the function "manipulateUsername" by reference as an event listener to another smaller component.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserInput from './components/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './components/UserOutput';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    username: "Max",
    age: 30
  }    

  manipulateUsername = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      username: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <UserOutput name="Jenny" age="32"></UserOutput>        
        <UserOutput name={this.state.username} age={this.state.age}></UserOutput>        
        <UserInput setNameFunction={this.manipulateUsername} name={this.state.username}></UserInput>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In my UserInput.js, the onChange event listener gets passed the function reference "manipulateUsername" from the main App component.

```
import React from 'react';
import './UserInput.css';


const userInput = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="UserInput" >
            <input type="text" value={props.name} onChange={props.setNameFunction}></input>
        </div>
    )
}

export default userInput;
```

**This now may sound like a stupid question, but how does the onChange() function actually "know" that it has gotten a function passed as a reference, and how does it automatically execute that function? Because I did not call the function in this code like with parentheses:**

```
onChange={props.setNameFunction()}
```

instead, I just left the function as is..? `onChange={props.setNameFunction}`

**Secondly, I would like to know, how javascript manages to "pass" values implicitly to other functions, e.g in the app.js "manipulateUser" function, it always gets passed an event parameter (also if I leave out this parameter, I think). How does this work behind the scenes? Because in the onChange-function, I am calling my function, but I never pass that event parameter into it, so how does it work?**

Answer (score 1):

When you pass a function to onChange to be sure props contain a function that can be checked by following code.

```
onChange={typeof props.setNameFunction === "function"? props.setNameFunction : () => {}}
```

Secondly react provides onChange prop which is a function, it checks for type of props you have passed. If you pass other than function it will give an error.

Comment: ok nice to know, but how and why does it actually execute this setNameFunction? because there is nowhere an explicit call to the function with "()".

Comment: You have passed a callback to a input component as props as you do in normal component. As you execute a callback function in your component a react library executes a callback function. A function call is in the library of react.

Comment: ok so this all works with callbacks, didn't know that.. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

**By default,In JavaScript** Assignment and function argument passing of Object is done by passed by reference, and functions are Object in JavaScript. Only primitive's gets new memory location when gets assigned or pass to function.

Comment: I know, but that wasn't the actual question. I wanted to know when does javascript code know where and when to execute a function that it got from somewhere as a reference?

Comment: oh! then JavaScript Engine has Event queue where callback gets stored and called when JavaScript done with execution or done with another function/ callback from event queue as JavaScript internally runs synchronously.[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

Answer (score 0):

As javascript is functional programming language, passing of function as a parameter to another function is possible.

React wrapping actual events in a JavaScript wrapper, this is also makes react abstract to use. This better abstraction in react helps developer to build cross platform applications (like React Native for Android, IOS apps and Electron to build desktop applications).

If you do like this below code

```
<input type="text" value={props.name} onChange={props.setNameFunction()}></input>
```

the function will get executed at time of render not at onChange event of input.

But if you want to use `event` object while handling onChange event, try this

```
<input type="text" value={props.name} onChange={(event) => props.setNameFunction(event)}></input>
```

Hope it will help you. Thanks.